# draw call graph for C source codes using cppDepend

Tags: c, dependencies, cppdepend

I have a problem with using cppDepend tool. I have a source code which is written in C language and I need to draw Its dependency or call graph. cppDepend's  compiler's source code extension is set to c;cpp;cxx;cc but when I want to open source codes in C, the file chooser box only let me to choose source codes in C++.

What should I do????

Comment: I have tried to use it but it didn't work!!!!

Comment: @zari : Why do you need, for optimization purpose?

Comment: No. For architecture recovery.

Comment: Where you want to open source code in C? ProjectMaker? class browser? or another place?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux? Why don't you use other options? Hast to be cppDepend? Look at [cflow](http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/), [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) (my favorite), or even [gperf](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/?redir=1) (which outputs a callgraph in graph form!)

Comment: No in Windows. I used some other tools and I can't draw my purposed diagram. I tried cflow but it didn't work again!!! Ok I will try the tools you mentioned. Thanks a lot.